# C# List<MyObj> Remove method

Tags: c#, list

In C#  I have:

```
public class MyObj
{
 // methods and properties etc.
} 

List<MyObj> listOfObjects = new List<MyObj>();

listOfObjects.Remove( certainObj );
```

I want to know how does C# know that certainObj is IN the list ...Does it use the Equals() in the process of locating certainObj in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it uses the `Equals(...)` method of `MyObj`, which defaults to reference equality if the method has not been overridden.

More specifically, it uses the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which in turn looks if `MyObj` implements `IEquatable<T>`. If not, it will use the `myObj.Equals(object obj)` overload, which calls `Object.ReferenceEquals(...)` if not overridden.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx

> This method determines equality using
>   the default equality comparer
>   EqualityComparer.Default for T, the
>   type of values in the list.
>
> This method performs a linear search;
>   therefore, this method is an O(n)
>   operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 0):

Yep check out MSDN for List class it uses .Equals() method on the object for .Contains on a generic list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx